# How can I select an element with two classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<h2 class="first second">Red</h2>
<h2 class="second">Blue</h2>
<h2 class="first">Green</h2>
```

How can I select `h2` with `first` and `second` class?

<sub>thanks about answers</sub>

---

**Update:**

If I have another `h2` tag like this:

```
<h2 class="first second third">Default</h2>
```

it will be red with `h2.first.second` selector. Is there any way to select only element with `first` and `second` classes, not more.

Comment: To clarify, are you attempting to select ("Red"), or ("Blue","Green")?

Comment: @caleb.breckon I want to select Red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```css
h2.first.second {
    color: red;
}
```

This selects the `h2` element with both classes "first" and "second". Refer to the [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html) W3 recommendation for more info.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDjJs/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to select h2 with first and second class simutaneously

> h2.first.second

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utfkz) of the solution.

```
h2.first.second {
/* styles go here*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To select elements that have multiple classes simple use this:

```
h2.first.second
```

Note that there is no space between the classes, as apposed to the following which would select elements with the class of `second` which are inside a `h2` element with the class of `first`

```
h2.first .second
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select

```
.first.second {}
```

if you want only the first h2 to be selected. Make sure there is no space!

Answer (score 1):

The following rule matches any `h2` element whose class attribute has been assigned a list of whitespace-separated values that **includes** both "first" and "second":

```
h2.first.second { color: red }
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html)

But, to select an element whose class attribute exactly **equal** "first" and "second" I used this rule:

```
h2[class="first second"], h2[class="second first"] { color: red }
```

[**JsFiddle demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/hSY9w/)